# Changing cabal home dir

Tags: haskell, cabal

On Windows cabal uses UNC path as home folder:

```
\\EXAMPLE.EXAMPLE.COM\UserData\username\RF\AppData\Roaming\cabal\config
```

How can I set it explicitly to some folder on C:\ drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An excerpt from `cabal --help`:

```
Global flags:
 -h --help                         Show this help text
 -V --version                      Print version information
    --numeric-version              Print just the version number
------------------------ LOOK HERE ------------------------
    --config-file=FILE             Set an alternate location for the config
                                   file
------------------------ LOOK HERE ------------------------
    --sandbox-config-file=FILE     Set an alternate location for the sandbox
                                   config file (default:
                                   './cabal.sandbox.config')
    --default-user-config=FILE     Set a location for a cabal.config file for
                                   projects without their own cabal.config
                                   freeze file.
    --require-sandbox              Enable requiring the presence of a sandbox
                                   for sandbox-aware commands
    --no-require-sandbox           Disable requiring the presence of a sandbox
                                   for sandbox-aware commands
    --ignore-sandbox               Ignore any existing sandbox
    --ignore-expiry                Ignore expiry dates on signed metadata (use
                                   only in exceptional circumstances)
    --http-transport=HttpTransport Set a transport for http(s) requests.
                                   Accepts 'curl', 'wget', 'powershell', and
                                   'plain-http'. (default: 'curl')
    --enable-nix                   Enable Nix integration: run commands through
                                   nix-shell if a 'shell.nix' file exists
    --disable-nix                  Disable Nix integration: run commands
                                   through nix-shell if a 'shell.nix' file
                                   exists
```

Comment: I asked for changing **home directory**, not **specifying alternative location of the config file explicitly on commandline**, esp. that I'm running cabal indirectly via Stack. Usually change of home directory is done via environment variables, e.g. `STACK_ROOT` for Stack.

Comment: @LetMeSOThat4U Okay, then I don't understand your question yet. What effect do you want to cause that cannot be caused by changing the config file?

Comment: @LetMeSOThat4U On IRC, hvr also points out that there is an environment variable `CABAL_CONFIG` that does the same thing `--config-file` does.